# UIView animation is done instantly without regards to the duration or delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I'm having some difficulties animating one of my view's layoutConstraints:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.topLayoutConstraint?.constant = self.currentYPosition
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
```

Whatever the duration or the delay that I use, the animation is instantly done (my view jumps from previous position to the new one).

I've checked all the value and they are correct.
I've also checked and the animation and completion are called.

Any ideas ?

**EDIT:**

```
@objc private func viewDragged(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = recognizer.location(in: self.superview)

        switch recognizer.state {
        case .ended:

            if (recognizer.direction == .Down) {            // Collapsing the slide panel

                currentYPosition = parentViewHeight - minimumVisibleHeight - statusBarHeight - navBarHeight
            }
            else if (recognizer.direction == .Up) {       // Expanding the slide panel

                // Substracting `minimumVisibleHeight` so that the dragable part is hidden behind the navigation bar
                currentYPosition = -minimumVisibleHeight
            }

            self.topLayoutConstraint?.constant = self.currentYPosition
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
                }, completion: nil)
            break
        case .began:
            HomeSlidePanelContainerView.draggingPreviousPosition = location.y
        default:
            self.layoutIfNeeded()

            if (location.y < (parentViewHeight - minimumVisibleHeight - statusBarHeight - navBarHeight)
                || location.y > (statusBarHeight + navBarHeight)) {

                currentYPosition -= HomeSlidePanelContainerView.draggingPreviousPosition - location.y
                topLayoutConstraint?.constant = currentYPosition
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
            HomeSlidePanelContainerView.draggingPreviousPosition = location.y
            break
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` before `layoutIfNeeded()`?

Comment: @werediver like in the animation or before ? In either case, nop I haven't

Comment: take this line `self.topLayoutConstraint?.constant = self.currentYPosition` out of the animation block.

Comment: @holex already done (see edit), but nothing changes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to find the solution. This might help others so I'm answering my own question.

What I was doing was something like this:

```
self.topLayoutConstraint?.constant = self.currentYPosition

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {               
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

As you can see, I'm changing a value, `topLayoutConstraint`, that is a constraint on `self` which is a `UIView`.

Then I'm trying to animate that change by calling `self.layoutIfNeeded` in an animation closure.

The thing here is that `layoutIfNeeded()` applies to subviews and not the view itself. So in my case i was trying to animate the layout of `self`'s subviews instead of `self` itself.

Changed `self.layoutIfNeeded()` to `self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` and Voilà !!

Comment: I was always setting constraint.constant to animate but don't get how this works. Need to check on docs.

Answer (score 0):

Set the constraint before the animation block:

```
self.topLayoutConstraint?.constant = self.currentYPosition

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {               
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I assume the error is somewhere else than. Maybe  post more code.

Comment: default: case and  .began case are not animated. Debug to make sure you are in the right case.

Comment: I'm aware of that. As I said, the animation and completion blocks are executed ... :/ so I'm in right case

Answer (score 0):

I often use Snapkit or Masonry do autolayout, maybe you can try it.It is familiar with Apple's autolayout, it is awesome!For example sub code I use today:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
 minLabel.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view.snp.centerY)
                    }
})
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Don't really want to include a pod just to do a single animation :/ but I agree, it's an interesting lib

Comment: If there is no complier error and when you refresh view , the UI sometime is correct sometime is not.It maybe thread issue.Get your animate and autolayout in a sync.